# Rails5 Beta3 not convert form submit model name to camel case

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

in Rails 4. This is will show "New Post" as button value in a new record form.
But in Rails 5. It show "New post" as button value.

How cloud I still use the old way in Rails 5.

Comment: PR in Rails https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22764. This is the reason about this change.